# Kubernetes pods wrting to persistent volume, need to push the logs to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

I have kubernetes pods writing logs to multiple log files using a persistent volume - nfs drive. I need a way to push the logs real time from the log files to ELastic Search.
I am trying to set up a filebeat as the sidecar container but not sure how it will help

Please suggest recommended approach with examples.

Comment: Filebeat can read the log files and send it to elasticsearch, but reading from network volumes, such as nfs, is [not recommended](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-network-volumes.html#filebeat-network-volumes) by elastic.

Comment: is there anyother way to read application log files from NFS drive and send it to ElasticSearch

Comment: Not that I know of, maybe fluentd, but I think fluentd could suffer from the same problems reading from NFS. You can use Filebeat to read from NFS, just know that you can have unexpected issues, like the file being read from the begin again.